# iOS Non-Renewable subscriptions IAP - Max limit which can be created in itunes connect

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to integrate In-App purchases for one of my app. Which contains digital products which needs to be available for user to access for certain time from the date of purchase.

So the suitable product type is non-renewable subscription. But just want the cross check, if there is any limit for non-renewable subscriptions products count which can be created, since it is a subscription type.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be afraid of any limitation for reasonable number of subscription item. Because I didn't found any limitation in Apple documentation, nor it AppStore Connect (where you create your in-app items).

And I already have 50 subscription items in 10 Subscription Groups without any trouble.

P.S. When creating multiple subscription items, keep in mind to group/split them into Subscription Groups and rank them within each group: see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) for more.

Comment: Subscription groups are only applicable for auto renewing subscriptions.